# Have Dynamical values for my parameters in the Request payload (POST x-www-form-urlencoded)

Tags: apiblueprint

Is there a way (and does it make sense even) to have dynamical values for my request parameters (in my case POST application/x-www-form-urlencoded that has two parameters username and password) which can be altered based on some function or a returned value from the server from a previous request?

The motivation being that i have a register-new-user request which i run from time to time off apiary.io and unless i manually change the example value for the username i get a "use already exists" response instead of 201 i want (since this request was already run with the username in the example).

What i'd like to have instead is a value in the API documentation that will change on each execution of the API call (either using some random number there, or to be able to have it take a value returned from a previous request).

Is there anything you can suggest to solve my "user already exists" response for register-new-user API call?

Here is my current API documentation (the relevant part):

```
## Registration [/users.json]
The `/users.json` resource handles registration of new user

### Register a New Patient [POST]
Register a new patient action sends email and password and registers
the new user in case it doesn't already exist

+ Request (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
    + Attributes (Test User)

    + Body

        user[email]=username@example.com&user[password]=123456

+ Response 201 (application/json)

        {
            "id":500
        }

# Data Structures
## Test User (object) 
+ "user[email]" (string): "username@example.com" - user email
+ "user[password]" (string): "123456" - user password
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can partially simulate this in the Apiary mock server by passing a header in your call, for example:

`Prefer: status=200`

See https://help.apiary.io/tools/mock-server/#multiple-responses

In general the mock server is not yet flexible and programmable enough to fully do what you describe, for example conditionals, dynamic variables or random responses.

We are working on enhancing this. If you'd like you may comment here on your requirements:
https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/58

Feel free to also ping us in Apiary (in-app chat) or on support@apiary.io.

Thanks